# Block 1 out of 2 domains only from search engines

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I am hosting two domains on the same server and in the same directory. I want to block 1 of the domain from search engines but don't want to block the other one.

Let's say I have:

www.site1.com and www.site2.com

Both are pointing to the same IP on the server and I only want to block site2.com and not site1.com.

How do i do that? Any clues?

Comment: This question is more suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `robots2.txt` with this code:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Then put this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots2.txt [L,NC]
```

1. This will serve `/robots2.txt` for all `/robots.txt` requests for `site2`.
2. Regular `/robots.txt` will be used for `site1`.
3. Only `site2` will be blocked from search engines.

Comment: thanks. So, i only create a robots2.txt and not a robots.txt as well? Is that correct?

Comment: o.k..thanks. Hope it works. I appreciate your time :)

Comment: Yes it will work. For any issues/questions feel free to leave a comment here anytime and I will respond.

Comment: +1, Ha, rewriting robots.txt? That was an interesting question, with a perfect answer.  :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81 yes it was indeed an interesting problem to solve.

Comment: Yes, I'm loving discovering the wide range of things people are wanting to achieve through url rewriting.